# Does this qualify for the Highstock NON-COMMERCIAL LICENSE?

Tags: highcharts

If a commercial company releases a no-charge Open Source stand-alone application, does the qualify them to use Highcharts/Highstock product in that program under the non-commercial license?

The FAQ appears to read as: because your product allows "Source code editing" you can use the high stock without purchasing the license.  It is notable that they may also purchase the license to reward HighSoft for there hard-work and to gain access to support.

See: http://shop.highsoft.com/faq

```
WHEN CAN I USE THE NON-COMMERCIAL LICENSE?
You can use our software for free under the non-commercial license when you are:

* A student, university or a public school
* A non-profit organisation
* Developing and testing applications using Highcharts/Highstock
Source editing is allowed.
```

Comment: Please contact with us by support@highcharts.com which answer for this sepcific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got permission to publish this email reply:

---

On Fri, Jul 18, 2014 at 3:45 AM, Highsoft Sales  wrote:

Hi James!

I am pleased to hear that you are interested in our product.

In regards to Open Source projects, there are some important issues for us to emphasize:

- Our license model is unfortunately not compatible with any open source license like Apache 2 or any GPL.
  We offer free license for non profits organizations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-profit_organization)
  The software-code is free for download from our website for all customers with a valid license.
- Our business model is heavily based on the income from license payments.

In order to implement Highstock in accordance to our business model, either you/your company or your clients will need a Highstock License.